# Nancy: Why do xUnit tests depend on the Razor view engine?

Tags: nancy

Why do Nancy / xUnit tests in Visual Studio 11 depend on the Razor view engine? I am using the Nancy default view engine (SSVE). Do I need a different bootstrapper?

**Test**

```
[Fact]
public void Register_mentor_Should_redirect_to_mentor_home()
{
    // Given
    var bootstrapper = new DefaultNancyBootstrapper();
    var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);

    //When
    var response = browser.Post("/register", (with) =>
    {
        with.HttpRequest();
        with.FormValue("role", "mentor");
    });

    // Then
    response.ShouldHaveRedirectedTo("/mentor");
}
```

I get the following exception

**Exception**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. You are seeing that exception for two reasons

- You have installed the Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor nuget, which also includes Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.dll (as of Nancy 0.10). The dll is there to enable design-time intellisense for the Nancy razor engine. The file is copied to your \bin directory on each build, through a post-build event that the Nuget installs
- The BadImageFormatException is because we had a bug in our project Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders project which made it only target x86 systems. This has been addressed in the upcoming 0.11 release and is already checked into the master branch

So to fix this, remove the Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor nuget (you said you only used SSVE views) and every thing should work fine (uninstalling the nuget will also uninstall the post-build event hook)

Comment: PM> uninstall-package Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor
Uninstall-Package : Unable to find package 'Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor'.

Comment: I did have razor installed for me as part of the Cassette.Nancy package but this was uninstalled a few days ago. However you were right, it was the pesky Razor.BuildProviders dll hanging around in my \bin directory. All I needed to to do was perform a Clean on the project, then decide I didn't trust that and delete the bin folder completely, then re-compile. Now my unit tests work. Thanks.